# Scripting Issue - Unity5 C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Code:

```
if (direction.magnitude > 5f) { 
    this.transform.Translate (0, 0, 0.001f);
    anim.SetBool ("isWalking", true);
}// if 

else
    print ("MAGNITUDE: " + direction.magnitude + " IS GREATER THAN 5");
```

Result:

```
MAGNITUDE: 0.786 IS GREATER THAN 5
```

How did **0.786** became greater than **5**?

The direction variable is a Vector3 and Vector3.magnitude returns float I don't really know what's happening.

Thanks.

Comment: it became greater because YOU said so. actually the output is in the else meaning its smaller ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, the print message should be inside the `if` block

```
    if (direction.magnitude > 5f) {
        this.transform.Translate (0, 0, 0.001f);
        anim.SetBool ("isWalking", true);
        print ("MAGNITUDE: " + direction.magnitude + " IS GREATER THAN 5");
    }
```

Another possibility : the comparison symbol. I guess you wanted to put `<` rather than `>`

```
    if (direction.magnitude < 5f) { // ← HERE
        this.transform.Translate (0, 0, 0.001f);
        anim.SetBool ("isWalking", true);
    }// if 
    else
        print ("MAGNITUDE: " + direction.magnitude + " IS GREATER THAN 5");
```

Or maybe, you need to change your message ;)

```
    if (direction.magnitude > 5f) {
        this.transform.Translate (0, 0, 0.001f);
        anim.SetBool ("isWalking", true);
    }// if 
    else
        print ("MAGNITUDE: " + direction.magnitude + " IS LOWER THAN 5");
```

Comment: I think from my code I wanted to check if the magnitude is greater than 5.

the else statement or even if I just print the value of `direction.magnitude` beforehand I always get 0.786 and we all know that 0.786 is not greater than 5. Maybe I'm messing up with the types. imo, however I don't know what was wrong. Thanks

Comment: Hey Hellium, what can you say about the result 0.786? did you really think that 0.786 is greater than 5? I'm really getting confused. Please do mind the whole question. `0.786 > 5 // True?`

Comment: For sure it is not ! Check the 3 fixes I suggested in my answer. It really depends on what you really want to do.

Comment: Hey, Hellium! I think I was just confused of what I'm expecting to happen I find my question a bit dumb so I flagged it as unclear question. I think you got the right answer so. Thanks!